# Crystal Reports - Summary report containing data from 2 reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 2 separate crystal reports that both work with specific item numbers.
Each report is using a number of formula's and select filter to isolate the data I need.

The 1st report is counting the number of items added in each month.
Jan-16  31
Feb-16  23
Mar-16  16
Apr-16  23

The 2nd report is counting how many items have been audited each month.
Jan-16  31
Feb-16  23
Mar-16  16
Apr-16  23

These are not linked so I cannot populate both datasets into the same report.

I need the above data to be outputted on a single report
See what I am trying to output in the image below:
http://s31.postimg.org/it2og90ij/cystal_summary.jpg

The only way I have been able to output in the format I need is to export both reports to Excel and create a summary sheet in excel.

I am thinking there must be an easier way to do this and output in a single crystal report?
From reading it looks like a shared array may help me but I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You need to use sub reports...place two sub reports in a single report and dont link the reports now as you exactly said you can manipulate the data using arrays take data from both sub reports in msin report and display data

Comment: How complicated are the queries and what database are you using? My suggestion is likely going to be just to combine the two queries via SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new container report with a single table containing a datetime field with all possible years and months you will ever need (e.g. 1/1/2016,2/1/2016,3/1/2016...).  For the table you can use Excel, a new DB table, or a view of an existing db table with a distinct row per month.

Create a year-month formula (something that returns 2016-01, for example) in the container report as well as your "Items Added" report and your "Items Audited" report.

Back in the container report, create a group on your year-month formula.

In the group header, next to Group #1 Name, insert your "Items Added" and "Items Audited" reports as subreports.  Line them up next to each other as shown in your jpg.

Add subreport links on Year-Month to each sub and then format both subs to just return one value in the report footer. Suppress everything else.

Comment: Hopefully this is good enough. But note that the subreports will each run once *per* group.

Comment: Yep- not very performant but is a crystal-only solution. If the two record sets are guaranteed to have the exact same months this could be done as a crosstab in the report header with a sub report of the other crosstab alongside.